# How to make onClickListener receive Intent information from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to make a button use some data from another activity, I did seach, but I didn't find out how.

The onClickListener doesn't work.

Here is the code inside my onCreate:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_message);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
        ScrollTextView scrolltext = (ScrollTextView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_text);
        scrolltext.setText(msg);
        scrolltext.setTextSize(220);
        scrolltext.startScroll();

        super.onResume();


        DialogFragment mDialog = new GeneralDialogFragment();
        mDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog TAG");

        ImageButton mImageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.image_button);
        mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                //I'm sure this is not the to make this button works. What code should I put here to pass this data to the ScrollTextView?
                scrolltext.setText(msg);
                scrolltext.setTextSize(220);
                scrolltext.startScroll();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This two lines that you wrote are just used to get information from the previous activity that was executing

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
String msg = intent.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
```

If you want to use data from another activity at any time, you have to save the data in the previous activity with these lines:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("msg", "MESSAGE");
 editor.commit();
```

and call it on your activity like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String yourmessage = prefs.getString("msg", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("msg", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The code you add woks. I know this because I tested in another button, but now the problem is to make it work from a button inside a custom fregmentDialog. I Don't know where to put the onClickListener in this case. Maybe I'll ask this in another question.